# Boot hangs at "Started Hostname Service." with no errors

Tags: boot, server

I am using 18.04 LTS Server. I built my new server in a 1U case and had absolutely zero problems with the system *until*  I put the top of the case on it. Unfortunately, there is an excess of wires inside the case, so there was some difficulty in getting the cover in place. The server refused to boot with the cover in place, so I took it off. I double checked all wires to make sure nothing got disconnected but I had problems booting. I could boot into recovery mode and then resume, but it will not boot normally. I would see errors in CPU or memory. I tried to boot my Ubuntu Server LiveUSB stick and it failed. On a whim, I cleared the CMOS. I then ran several tests from an Ultimate Boot CD liveUSB drive and found no errors with either the CPU (8th generation i5) or the 16GB of RAM. I then tried booting again and now it goes through the boot process with no errors seen until I get to "Started Hostname Service." It has hung there for an hour, I was hoping it was just trying to synchronize some data or something but I figure an hour should be good enough time to expect for that.

[boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSlL9.jpg)